# How to make background SLIGHTLY fade from top and bottom?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to slightly fade the top and bottom of my `<div>`'s background, but every time it ends up fading almost till the middle which is not what I want.

I'd like to mush the border of the two `<div>`s.

```
background: linear-gradient(white, #c3faec, white);
```

Have used this and tried to change the % on both colour without success.

Comment: add two more divs to top and bottom, using css change it's position and background color to match webpage's background color

Comment: please add a snippet of your code, it will be easier to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two CSS pseudo elements and configure the gradients independently with the element's height and colour gradient stops.

Example: https://codepen.io/giumagnani/pen/ZZpmje

```css
div {
  margin: 100px 0;
  background: #2222ff;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 100%);
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, white 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set explicit distances for each colour to start and stop, then set your middle colour in two positions to make it solid for that area.

```css
div {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 5vh;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0%, red 10%, red 90%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the direction too in the gradient property. Hope this works.

```css
div {
  height:100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,white, #c3faec, white);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make background slightly fade from top and bottom by this code of css

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 10%, black 80%, white 10%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    "your title"
  </title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```